# Atributo selected a select generado automáticamente

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy realizando el llenado de un `select` de manera dinámica desde **AJAX** el problema es que al momento de editar el registro quiero que me seleccione el que se encuentra seleccionado en **BD**.

Código para generar el `select` desde **AJAX**:

```
function cargarGrupo() {
    var grupo = $("#cbxid_asignacion");
    var datos = {
        "id_carrera": $("#cbxid_carrera").val(),
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'includes/getGrupo.php',
        data: datos,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function () {
            alert("Error en la petición a la base de datos");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("cbxid_asignacion").innerHTML += "<option value=''>Seleccione el grupo</option>";
            $.each(data, function (id, value) {
                document.getElementById("cbxid_asignacion").innerHTML += "<option value='" + id + "'>" + value + "</option>";
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Intento seleccionarlo de la siguiente manera pero como el código se genera de manera automática no lo realiza, si recibe el valor que le envio.

```
function enviarDatos(valor) {
    console.log(valor);
    var element = document.getElementById("cbxid_asignacion");
    element.value = valor;
}
```

Lo que busco es hacer en el método `cargarGrupo()` es mandarle el valor a seleccionar pero no se como realizar el `selected` en el `each` de la respuesta.

```
function cargarGrupo(valor) {
    var grupo = $("#cbxid_asignacion");
    var datos = {
        "id_carrera": $("#cbxid_carrera").val(),
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'includes/getGrupo.php',
        data: datos,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function () {
            alert("Error en la petición a la base de datos");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("cbxid_asignacion").innerHTML += "<option value=''>Seleccione el grupo</option>";
            $.each(data, function (id, value) {
                //Aquí pondría un if pero no se como realizarlo
                document.getElementById("cbxid_asignacion").innerHTML += "<option value='" + id + "'>" + value + "</option>";
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probando con el código ya solucione el problema de la siguiente manera:

```
function cargarGrupo(valor) {
    var element = document.getElementById("cbxid_asignacion");
    var datos = {
         "id_carrera": $("#cbxid_carrera").val(),
    }

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'includes/getGrupo.php',
    data: datos,
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function () {
        alert("Error en la petición a la base de datos");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        element.innerHTML += "<option value=''>Seleccione el grupo</option>";
        $.each(data, function (id, value) {
            element.innerHTML += "<option value='" + id + "'>" + value + "</option>";
        });
        //Se envia al elemento el valor a seleccionar
        element.value = valor;
    }
});
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

así como tienes tu elemento valor, que estoy suponiendo que es el que quieres que se seleccione, lo único que tienes que hacer es en tu método each ajustar de ésto:

```
document.getElementById("cbxid_asignacion").innerHTML += "<option value='" + id + "'>" + value + "</option>";
```

A algo como:

```
document.getElementById("cbxid_asignacion").innerHTML += "<option"+ ( id == valor ? 'selected' : '' ) +" value='" + id + "' >" + value + "</option>";
```

No se si tengas experiencia con el operador ternario pero practicamente el siguiente fragmento de codigo:

```
( id == valor ? 'selected' : '' )
```

Hace lo siguiente: Si el id es igual al valor que quieres seleccionar, entonces devuelves 'selected' y sino, devuelves solo un espacio vacío, eso hará que en la concatenación, sino es igual, devuelva un espacio vacio y no se seleccione nada, y si es igual, el option tendrá asignado el valor "selected" y aparecerá como seleccionado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta pero no me funciono :(